# python3 how to change the atribute .P0 with passing argument to call

Tags: python, arguments, sensors

I am trying to use passing a choice of pins to the raspberry py when creating channels and want to change only the .P(value) when calling the method.  For if I call the class in another class I currently have to import all libraries again with the way it is now.  Below is code.

```
import busio
import digitalio
import board
import adafruit_mcp3xxx.mcp3008 as MCP
```

from adafruit_mcp3xxx.analog_in import AnalogIn

```
def createChannel(self, channelNumber):
    # create the spi bus
    spi = busio.SPI(clock=board.SCK, MISO=board.MISO, MOSI=board.MOSI)
    # create the cs (chip select)
    cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D22)
    # create the mcp object
    mcp = MCP.MCP3008(spi, cs)
    self.channelNumber = channelNumber
    chan = self.channelNumber
    chan = AnalogIn(mcp, self.channelNumber)
    rawValue = chan.voltage 
    return rawValue
```

Then I call it like

```
sensor = createChannel()
rawValue = sensor.createChannel(MCP.P0)
```

So when I create another class to use the sensor retrieved data and I call the function I need to import all the libraries again that works with the MCP. I want to call it like this

```
sensor = createChannel()
rawValue = sensor.createChannel(P0)
```

But I can not find a way to just change the last part 'MCP.P0') by passing a argument in the call that works.

So when I create the other class I have to do this and import all libraries again

```
def sensorOne(self):
    # create the spi bus
    spi = busio.SPI(clock=board.SCK, MISO=board.MISO, MOSI=board.MOSI)
    # create the cs (chip select)
    cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D22)
    # create the mcp object
    mcp = MCP.MCP3008(spi, cs)
    #get date and time
    outTime = str(datetime.now())
    # instance of createSpi class.  so if tds sensor is connected to pin 0 you do as below.  I will also do ph on pin 2 but comment it out for I am not sure if anyting is connected there yet.
    sensor = createChannel()
    #get data from sensor on pin 1
    outData = sensor.createChannel(MCP.P1) 
    return outTime, outData
```

If spacing is not hundred persent please excuse I can not see for I am blind, but the code works just need to try and be able to change just the .P0 to for instance P1 by passing a argument to the call.

Thank you

Comment: What is MCP?  Can you access channels like MCP['P0']?

Comment: It is a analog to digital converter library for converting analog data to digital data from a sensor on a raspberry

Comment: Sorry, I meant what `type` is it?  Without knowing what you are importing, or what access methods those things support it is hard to help.  Can you make a shorter, minimal code example that I can run, with one toy file defining a simple class that references MCP.P1, and another toy file that imports the first and wants to use your simplified class?  Ideally, about three lines of code in each file, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you have a py with the mcp3008 board?

Comment: Does MCP come from an `import`?  If so, you could edit your question and show the import.  Also, instead of showing a complex `sensorOne` method out of context without the class you could make a toy simple class that does very little except has a toy `simpleOne` method that just returns `type(MCP.P1)` or something, just to access `P1`.  Then we would be able to try different ways of making P1 accessible to users of your class.

Comment: Yes it is a import, will edit and add it.  Think it is a variable from a __init__ method. So if some or other placeholder could work maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can define constants `P0` to `P7` in your module that defines `createChannel`, and then other files can import those constants from that module instead of getting them from MCP directly.  Also, you can just specify a channel with an integer from 0 to 7.

I found some online [documentation for adafruit_mcp3xxx.mcp3008](https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/mcp3xxx/en/latest/api.html#implementation-notes).  I think it means the channel names like MCP.P0 and MCP.P1 are really just integer values like 0 and 1, respectively.

> The ADC chips’ input pins (AKA “channels”) are aliased in this library
> as integer variables whose names start with “P” (eg MCP3008.P0 is
> channel 0 on the MCP3008 chip). Each module that contains a driver
> class for a particular ADC chip has these aliases predefined
> accordingly. This is done for code readability and prevention of
> erroneous SPI commands.

You can make channel names available to users of your `createChannel` method by defining constants `P0`, `P1` and so forth in the module that defines `createChannel`.

```
## File createChannel.py

import adafruit_mcp3xxx.mcp3008 as MCP

# Alias the channel constants for convenience.
P0 = MCP.P0
P1 = MCP.P1
# etc.
P7 = MCP.P7

class createChannel():
    def createChannel(self, channelNumber):
        # ... Do stuff with channelNumber.
        return channelNumber  # Or whatever you need to return.
```

In another file that wants to use `createChannel` you can import the channel constants as well as the method.  Alternatively, I think you can just access a channel by specifying an integer from 0 to 7.

```
## Another file.

from createChannel import createChannel, P0, P1, P7

sensor = createChannel()
# Access a single pin.
rawValue = sensor.createChannel(P0)

# Access each pin.
rawBus = [sensor.createChannel(pin) for pin in range(8)]
```